# Undefined method `reflect_on_association` using Mongoid, Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I'm learning me some Rails! But right now, I can't seem to get past an error RSpec is throwing. The error is as follows:

```
  1) EntryMethodsController POST create with valid params creates a new EntryMethod
     Failure/Error: post :create,
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `reflect_on_association' for "4e94ca4f66472f02ff00000a":String
     # ./app/controllers/entry_methods_controller.rb:43:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/entry_methods_controller_spec.rb:48:in `block (4 levels) in '

Finished in 0.29409 seconds
13 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/entry_methods_controller_spec.rb:47 # EntryMethodsController POST create with valid params creates a new EntryMethod
Done.
```

#### Test

```
  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      before :each do
        @contest = FactoryGirl.create(:contest)
      end

      after :each do
        @contest.destroy
      end

      it "creates a new EntryMethod" do
        expect {
          post :create,
               :contest => @contest,
               :entry_method => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:url_entry_method, :contest => @contest)
        }.to change(@contest.entry_methods, :count).by(1)
      end
   end
 end
```

#### Controller

```
def create
  @entry_method = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
                  .entry_methods.new(params[:entry_method])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry_method.save
      format.html { redirect_to @entry_method, notice: 'Entry method was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @entry_method, status: :created, location: @entry_method }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @entry_method.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

#### Models

```
class Contest
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name, :type => String
  field :rules, :type => String
  field :start_date, :type => Time
  field :end_date, :type => Time

  embeds_many :entry_methods
end

class EntryMethod
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :url, :type => String
  field :string, :type => String

  embedded_in :contest
end
```

Thanks, SO awesome people. :)

Answer (score 2):

I reckon this is because you're passing through a full `@contest` object to the parameters of the `create` action, when it's actually going to be expecting a `Hash` of attributes.

You can fix this by changing your call to that action to this:

```
post :create,
     :contest => @contest.attributes,
     ...
```

I would also *not* get FactoryGirl to create the object for you, as that may lead to uniqueness validations or whatever possibly failing. You should be using `FactoryGirl.build`, and not `FactoryGirl.create`.

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  Would you mind taking a look?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133036/rails-routes-with-id-not-working