# rails routes with :id not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, activeresource

I have a model called Schedule that belongs_to a project.  A project has_one schedule.  I am trying to follow CRUD conventions but having some difficult.  I have a page that lists all the projects and has a link next to each project to create a schedule.  I started out with the following in my route file:

```
resources :schedules
```

Here's the problem.  In the url of the 'new schedule' page there needs to be an :id that refers to the project that the schedule belongs to, that way when the schedule is created it will belong to the proper project.  I don't know of a way to do that with resources, so I changed my routes code to:

```
match 'schedules/new/:id', to: 'schedules#new', as: :new_schedule, via: [:get, :post]
resources :schedules, except: [:new, :create]
```

For some reason, this page is blank.  It's just white.  How do I fix my routes?  Thanks.

UPDATE:

I also tried changing my routes to the following:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :schedules
end
```

This makes the url for a new schedule in the form of:

```
/projects/:project_id/schedules/new(.:format)
```

I think this is how it should be done, however, the form for new schedules is written as

```
form_for @schedule
```

and that produces the following error:

```
undefined method `schedules_path'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a nested resource/route, you need to pass an array containing both the `@schedule` instance variable (holding the new `Schedule` object) along with the @project instance variable (holding the parent `Project` object) to your `form_for`:

```
form_for [@project, @schedule]
```

**EXPLANATION**:

Your named match route (i.e., `match 'schedules/new/:id'`) fails to route because the `schedules#new` controller action is RESTful and thus [does *not* accept an `id` parameter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). However, you correctly amended your route in your update – the parent-child association between projects/schedules should indeed be represented in your routes by nesting your resources.

The resulting path – `/projects/:project_id/schedules/new` – requires that an array of objects be passed to your `form_for` helper. The first must be an existing `Project` object (thus satisfying the `:project_id` parameter) and the second must be a new `Schedule` object (which, by definition, will not yet have an `id` attribute assigned).

Comment: Thanks.  That almost fixed it.  But for some reason it won't save.  It gives me the following error though when I submit the form:  'can't write unknown attribute `schedule_id''.

Comment: What line is this error on? Please update your question to include your controller code/stacktrace.

Comment: Some of the quickest and best advice i've ever received on stack overflow.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: You were very helpful with this.  After i finished this, I ran into another issue.  I'd appreciate your help.  I posted the question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152691/in-rails-routes-nested-resources-is-causing-white-screen  .  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added an answer to your question... please consider accepting/upvoting if it addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom views, such **`shedules/get`**, you should add line **`get "shedules/get"`** in **`config/routes.rb`** file

Answer (score 0):

If you nest the resources that way, all schedule method helpers will need to be preceded with *project* or *projects*. For example, *project*_schedules_path. That's why you're getting that error. You have a link using the wrong path helper.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects